# Error using web test performance visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, webtest

I am using visual studio 2012 ultimate top create web performance tests.

I have created a test, manually, and i'm trying to get a value, through a web test plugin, from the App.config file in the solution.

Code in App.config:

```
(xml code)
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="PaymentServiceURL" value="MyURL" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
...
</connectionStrings>
```

Plugin code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;
using PaymentServiceAPITestNew.ConfigManager;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;


public class Init : WebTestPlugin
{
    public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
    {
        //List<APIObj> testList = null;
        string feedsURL = MyConfigManager.GetAppSettings("PaymentServiceURL");
        e.WebTest.Context["PaymentServiceURL"] = feedsURL;
    }
     .....
```

Code MyConfigManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using log4net;
using System.IO;

public static class MyConfigManager
{
  ...
    public static string GetConnectionString(string key)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (connectionStrings == null || (connectionStrings != null && connectionStrings.Count == 0))
        {
            connectionStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);
            foreach (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings conn in config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
                connectionStrings.Add(conn.Name, conn.ConnectionString);
        }

        connectionStrings.TryGetValue(key, out result);
        return result;
    }
    ...
```

the web test uses the plugin that was supposed to go to the app.config and get the PaymentServiceUrl, but he is no using that plugin.

The result is:
Request failed: Context parameter 'PaymentServiceURL' not found in test context

and

Request failed: Exception in PreWebTest event: Could not load file or assembly 'PaymentServiceAPITestNew, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

I have used the NuGet package called Trove Nini and works quite well for getting config file info.